# Wrong vertex order in geom_line plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Getting a strange ordering of vertices in a `geom_line` plot.  Left hand plot is base R; right is ggplot.

[image]

Here's the [shapefile](http://inspire.misoportal.com/geoserver/transport_direct_railnetwork/wfs?amp;version=2.0.0&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=transport_direct_railnetwork:railnetwork&SRSNAME=EPSG:27700&outputFormat=shape-zip) I'm working with.  This will reproduce the plot:

```
require(ggplot2); require(maptools)
rail = readShapeLines('railnetworkLine.shp')
rail_dat = fortify(rail[1,])
ggplot(rail_dat) + geom_line(aes(long, lat, group=group)) + coord_equal()
```

Any idea what is causing this?  The data order of fortify seems correct, as plotting separately `lines()` confirms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `geom_path` instead of `geom_line`. `geom_line` orders the data from lowest to highest x-value (`long` in this case) before plotting, but `geom_path` plots the data in the current order of the data frame rows.

```
ggplot(rail_dat) + 
  geom_path(aes(long, lat)) + coord_equal()
```

[image]